# Need help proving that an indicator/characteristic function on a closed interval [a,b] belongs to an $L^p$ space

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, characteristic-functions

For any $a,b$ real numbers with $a<=b$ and for any $p\in[1,\infty)$ I want to show that

$1_{[a,b]}\in L^p$

Now, I have a basic understanding of $L^p$ spaces and understand what a characteristic function looks like but I don't know how to prove this formally/by the book.

Comment: Hint: integral of indicator function is the measure of the underlying set.

Comment: Well, yeah the Lebesgue measure from my understanding of the closed interval [a,b] would be b-a which is exactly what I would get if I integrate 1 over that interval, but does this help in proving that it belongs to $L^p$?

Comment: Well, do you know the definition of $L^p$ space? You just need to show that appropriate integral is finite.

Comment: Does your "basic understanding" of $L^p$ include the _definition_? If not you have no understanding of $L^p$; if yes this should be clear.

Comment: Yeah the $L^p$ space contains functions whose pth powers are integrable.

Comment: And what is $|1|^p$?

Comment: Basically if the integral can be calculated and its a finite value then it belongs to the $L^p$ space, is what I understood.

Comment: It's 1, of course, but my proffessor said that this is not a formal proof and that there's more to it than just solving an 11th grade Riemann integral.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I have no idea what your professor means. $f\in L^p(\mu) \iff \left(\int |f|^p\,\mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p}< \infty$. If $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure, then $\left(\int |1_{[a,b]}|^p\,\mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p} = \left(\int |1_{[a,b]}|\,\mathrm d\mu \right)^{1/p} = (b-a)^{1/p}<\infty.$

Comment: Yeah, well when I asked he didn't try to tell me what exactly about my proof wasn't "academic/formal" but I guess i wrote $dx$ instead of $d\mu$ so that might have been what bothered him maybe.

Comment: There could be many reasons, only your professor can tell you precisely. It does seem like your professor was not convinced that you know the difference between Riemann and Lebesgue integration.

Comment: Hopefully that's it, thanks for your help.